# Difference between "sort < output" and "sort output"

Tags: linux, io

I just want to know the difference between:

```
sort < output
```

and

```
sort output
```

in Linux. How does it work exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed on unix.stackexchange here: [Performance difference between stdin and command line argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17194/performance-difference-between-stdin-and-command-line-argument)

In `sort < file` the shell performs redirection. It opens the file and passes the `stdin` file descriptor to the `sort` command which reads it.

In `sort file`, the `sort` command opens the file and then reads it.

Answer (score 2):

`sort < output` is telling the shell to use the contents of the file `output` and dump it to standard in for the command sort.

`sort output` is telling the command `sort` to use the file `output` on disk as it's source.

Many unix commands will accept either standard in or a file as input. The acceptance of standard in allows easier chaining of commands, often for things like `ps aux | grep "my process" | sort`. (List all processes, filter by "my process", sort lines).

Answer (score 1):

With `sort < input` the shell will run the `sort` command, and attach its input to the file 'input'.

With `sort input` the shell will run the `sort` command, and give it as parameter the string `input`. The `sort` command will then open the file to read it- content.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively there is no difference.

`sort < output` uses a feature of the shell called file redirection (see e.g. [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html))

The shell opens tile file `output` and attaches that open file as `stdin` to the sort program.

`sort output` gives the `output` filename as an command line argument to sort.

sort, as many utilities that takes a filename as an argument, will try to read input from `stdin` if you do not give it a filename as an argument, such as in the first case here. In both cases, sort will read the content of the `output` file, sort it, and write the result to stdout.